# Cannot dereference multidimensional array as expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int arr5[][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
```

The variable declaring a 2D array holds a pointer to the first element in the first array.  arr5 was defined as having 3 columns in each row. By adding 1 to arr5 we get the address of the first element in the second row, by adding 2 to arr5 we get the address of the first element in the third row.

```
int *row1 = arr5;
int *row2 = arr5 + 1;
int *row3 = arr5 + 2;
```

Dereferencing a pointer to an array gets the first element in the array.

```
printf("%d\n", *row1);  // prints 1
printf("%d\n", *row2);  // prints 4
printf("%d\n", *row3);  // prints 7
```

We can dereference the elements in those rows using [].

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  printf("%d%c", row1[j], (j==2)?'\n':' ');
} // prints 1 2 3
```

We can print the second row without using brackets. Row2 now holds the address of the first element in the second row.

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  printf("%d%c", *(row2+j), (j==2)?'\n':' ');
}  // prints 4 5 6
```

Why can't we substitute arr5+1 for row2 in the above example? row2 holds the address arr5+1.

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  printf("%d%c", *((arr5+1)+j), (j==2)?'\n':' ');
}  // prints what looks to be addresses
```

Comment: `int *row1 = arr5;` is a problem. `row1` is `int*`, `arr5` is not. `arr5` is `(int*)[3]`. `int *row1 = *arr5;` is OK as is `int *row2 = *(arr5 + 1);`

Comment: int *row1 = arr5; is not problematic.  printf("%d\n", *row1); prints the first element in the first row as expected.

Comment: It is only by happy circumstance. Turn on your compiler warnings, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS. *"warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type*"

Comment: 2D array problems have more clarity when the sample array is not a square array.  Consider a 3x4 array.

Comment: First sentence is wrong. There is no pointer. The array is 9 contiguous `int` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof`
>   operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or is a *string literal* used
>   to initialize an array, an expression that has type *"array of type"*
>   is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that
>   points to the initial element of the array object and is not an
>   lvalue.  [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and
>   function
>   designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

So when you access `arr5`, you are effectively using a *pointer to array of int [3]*. When you attempt to assign:

```
int *row1 = arr5;
```

You are attempting to assign `arr5` which has type `int(*)[3]` to `row1` which is `int*` resulting in the warning:

```
"initialization from incompatible pointer type"
```

To eliminate the warning you need to derefernce `arr5` resulting in type `int[3]` (which on access is converted to a pointer to the first element in the row) which is compatible with `int*`. For example, rearranging your example a bit, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int arr5[][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}},
        *row1 = *arr5,
        *row2 = *(arr5 + 1),
        *row3 = *(arr5 + 2);
    size_t  nrow = sizeof arr5 / sizeof *arr5,
            ncol = sizeof *arr5 / sizeof **arr5;

    puts ("By row:");
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ncol; j++)       /* output row1 */
        printf ("%3d", *(row1 + j));
    putchar ('\n');

    for (size_t j = 0; j < ncol; j++)       /* output row2 */
        printf ("%3d", *(row2 + j));
    putchar ('\n');

    for (size_t j = 0; j < ncol; j++)       /* output row3 */
        printf ("%3d", *(row3 + j));
    putchar ('\n');

    puts ("\nBy array:");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {     /* output arr5 */
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
            printf ("%3d", *(*(arr5 + i) + j));
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

(**note:** `row1[j]` and `arr5[i][j]` are generally more readable than their pointer notation equivalents)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr2arrayauto
By row:
  1  2  3
  4  5  6
  7  8  9

By array:
  1  2  3
  4  5  6
  7  8  9
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Good eye on the `= *arr5` part.

Comment: Only sharpened by the number of times I've stumbled off into something similar...

Comment: Agreed, the `int[3]` compatibility with `int*` is loose way of explaining the equivalence. The access of the row array by dereferencing the 2D array will itself result in a pointer to the first element of the row.

Comment: Wonderfully stated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Heed compiler warnings.  `*((arr5+1)+j)` is not an `int`, but an `int *`.

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]

Note: `(arr5+1)+j` is the same as `(arr5+1+j)`.  I suspect OP wanted `*(arr5+1)+j` here.

```
int main() {
    int arr5[][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("%d%c", *((arr5+1)+j), (j==2)?'\n':' '); // Warning here!!
    } 

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("%d%c", *(*(arr5+1)+j), (j==2)?'\n':' ');
      //               ^ 
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output

```
-13412 -13400 -13388  UB UB UB
4 5 6                 OK OK OK
```